# How to implement i18n into a micro-frontend application using Module Federation

Tags: next.js, react-intl, micro-frontend, formatjs, webpack-module-federation

What would you recommend for implementing i18n in a module federation micro-frontend next.js app?

At the moment (just starting) I got it working with `react-intl` by declaring the provider in the `_app.tsx`

```
  <IntlProvider locale={locale} defaultLocale={defaultLocale} messages={enMessages}>
    <SiteLayout>
      <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
    </SiteLayout>
  </IntlProvider>
```

And then when importing a component from another micro-frontend I am sending the `intl` object as param.

```
const XComponent = (await import('microApp2/XComponent')).default;
export default function ShellApp(): React.ReactElement {
  const intl = useIntl();
  return <XComponent intl={intl} />;
}
```

So that then in the micro-app component I can use it to format strings.

```
export default XComponent = (props: XComponentProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const { intl } = props;
  return (<div>{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'XComponent.Description' })}</div>);
}
```

The caveat of this approach is that I can only format using functions, I cannot make use of React DOM tags like:

`<FormattedMessage id="" />`

I didn't found much documentation so not sure this is a good approach. Those anybody knows or suggest any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sharing the same react from the host with your remote? What kind of error do you get by using the i18n components?

Comment: If I use `<FormattedMessage />` component, it basically says there is no `IntlProvider` provided. Which means is not getting access from the main app wrapper :(. That's why I need to pass down the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wrap each of your hosts with `<IntlProvider>` and get the value of your current language from a global source (like the URL or the state via a cookie etc).